# iOS autolayout view centered in parent, with margins and dynamic height

Tags: ios, dynamic, autolayout, margin, center

I'm creating a popup, using auto layout. My popup have a dynamic height, and must be centered in the window, with margins. It has a fixed width.

I added the following constraints:

- width = fixed value
- height less than or equal to a computed value
- top margin = container top margin + fixed value
- bottom margin = container bottom margin + fixed value
- center x = container center x
- center y = container center y

It seems to work, but Xcode shows a warning:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>
> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
>
> (
>
> ```
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7e572a40 V:|-(>=19)-[UIView:0x7a8bb6a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7e572140 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7e573620 UIView:0x7a8bb6a0.bottom >= UIView:0x7e572140.bottom + 19>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7e573950 UIView:0x7a8bb6a0.centerY == UIView:0x7e572140.centerY>"
> ```
>
> )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> ```
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7e573620 UIView:0x7a8bb6a0.bottom >= UIView:0x7e572140.bottom + 19>
> ```

What's wrong? If I remove the constraint that Xcode breaks, it does not work anymore (my popup is no longer visible).

Here is my constraints code:

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:_mainContainer,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.width,
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                           toItem:nil,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: UIPopup.defaultSize.width));

self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:_mainContainer,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.height,
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.lessThanOrEqual,
                                           toItem:nil,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant:popupHeight));

self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:_mainContainer,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.top,
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.greaterThanOrEqual,
                                           toItem:self.view,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.top,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant:verticalMargin));


self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:_mainContainer,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.bottom,
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.greaterThanOrEqual,
                                           toItem:self.view,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.bottom,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant:verticalMargin));

self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:_mainContainer,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.centerX,
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                           toItem:self.view,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.centerX,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: 0));

self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:_mainContainer,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.centerY,
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                           toItem:self.view,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.centerY,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: 0));
```

Comment: just use center y and height constraint with less or equal , remove the bottom and top margins

Comment: I can't do that: I need the top and bottom constraints so that the popup adjusts its size properly when the user rotates the device (and I'd like to avoid to have to handle it manually).

Comment: for that you can use another constraint for height and install/uninstall it, or update the constant of existing height constraint .

Comment: Remove the vertically center constraint. As you are already specifying the top and bottom constraint. Also try setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`to NO

Comment: Won't work in the case that my popup does not fill the window. I found the solution, see my answer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution:

- width = fixed value
- height <= parent height - 2*margin [with a 1000 priority]
- height = popup "real" height [with a 800 priority]
- center x = container center x
- center y = container center y

Code:

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:_mainContainer,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.width,
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                           toItem:nil,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: UIPopup.defaultSize.width));

let maxHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:_mainContainer,
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.height,
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.lessThanOrEqual,
                                             toItem:self.view,
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.height,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant:-2*verticalMargin);
maxHeightConstraint.priority = 1000;
self.view.addConstraint(maxHeightConstraint);

let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:_mainContainer,
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.height,
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                          toItem:nil,
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute,
                                          multiplier: 1,
                                          constant:popupHeight);
heightConstraint.priority = 800;
self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint);

self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:_mainContainer,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.centerX,
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                           toItem:self.view,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.centerX,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: 0));

self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:_mainContainer,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.centerY,
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                           toItem:self.view,
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.centerY,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: 0));
```